Remove \If and only have "do" in algortihm
I have the following code for an algorithm:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Pseudo-cod}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Statex \textbf{Step 1:} Solve Model.
        \Statex \textbf{Step 2:} Let $t\leftarrow 0$
        \For{$i \in \mathcal{I}$}
        \State Let $t \leftarrow t+1$
        \If{$\theta_{i} <-  r^{tot}$}
        \State $r^{tot}\times 0.9$
        \EndIf
        \EndFor
        \Statex \textbf{Step 3:}
        \If{$\theta_{i} \geq  r^{tot}$}
        \State stop and go to \textbf{Step 4}
        \EndIf
        \Statex \textbf{Step 4:} Solve the updated Model as IP.
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}

However, I now want to delete the If condition and only have do in the line.
I have already tried this, but it does not lead to the desired result.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Pseudo-cod}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Statex \textbf{Step 1:} Solve Model.
        \Statex \textbf{Step 2:} Let $t\leftarrow 0$
        \Statex \textbf{do}
        \qquad \State Let $t \leftarrow t+1$
        \Statex \qquad \If{$\theta_{i} <-  r^{tot}$}
        \Statex \qquad \qquad $r^{tot}\times 0.9$
        \Statex \qquad \EndIf
        \Statex \textbf{Step 3:}
        \If{$\theta_{i} \geq  r^{tot}$}
        \State stop and go to \textbf{Step 4}
        \EndIf
        \Statex \textbf{Step 4:} Solve the updated Model as IP.
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}

It should look like this:


Can you add a sketch how the result should look like?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Done!

Thanks! Much clearer now!

For concise algorithms in their writing and their formatting, you should take a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx .

Quick hack: define a new block and change the formatting to what you like
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\algblockdefx[NAME]{Do}{EndDo}{\textbf{Do}}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Pseudo-cod}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Statex \textbf{Step 1:} Solve Model.
        \Statex \textbf{Step 2:} Let $t\leftarrow 0$
        \Do
          \State Let $t \leftarrow t+1$ 
          \If{$\theta_{i} <-  r^{tot}$}
          \State $r^{tot}\times 0.9$
          \EndIf
        \EndDo
        \Statex \textbf{Step 3:}
        \If{$\theta_{i} \geq  r^{tot}$}
        \State stop and go to \textbf{Step 4}
        \EndIf
        \Statex \textbf{Step 4:} Solve the updated Model as IP.
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}


